# rosserial arduino Serial Port read failure

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-client, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've written a small sensor_msgs::Imu publisher on a arduino micro which works for a short time but crashes after some seconds with following status:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1402665675.175567] Note: publish buffer size is 512 bytes
[INFO] [WallTime: 1402665675.176102] Setup publisher on /imu_data [sensor_msgs/Imu]
[WARN] [WallTime: 1402665687.484972] Serial Port read returned short (expected 1 bytes, received 0 instead).
[WARN] [WallTime: 1402665687.485703] Serial Port read failure: 
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1402665699.934101] Lost sync with device, restarting...
```

I supposed this might be some buffer overflow, which is why I increased the nh.spinOnce() during the loop to no effect.

What does the message mean and how can I fix it? Thnx in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173564/rosserial-arduino-serial-port-read-failure/) by [honky](https://answers.ros.org/users/15546/honky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2014-06-13**:
You can check how much RAM you actually use with avr-size, see here : http://answers.ros.org/question/11159/problem-setting-up-rosserial_arduino/
and the rosserial documentation : http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The library I used had some weird Serial.print()'s in the middle of the code which kinda scrambled the communication with ros. Removing them all fixed the problem.

Thanks to al-dev for the link in the comments, had been an interesting read anyhow.

---

Originally posted by [honky](https://answers.ros.org/users/15546/honky/) with karma: 51 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-07-20**:
i have the same problem: lost sync , port read failure. How did you solve it please? I passed a message with 3 float members to arduino mega and it seems lost sync error all the time